# Cannot load gem rack/test

Tags: ruby, load-path

I'm trying to load `rack/test` into my application, but it's not working for some reason. When I do:

`gem list rack-test`

I get

`rack-test (0.6.2)`

So it's installed.

I can also get the path with:

`gem which rack/test`

which is

`/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb`

But then

`ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH.inspect; $LOAD_PATH << "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/"; require "rack/test"'`

yields

```
["/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux"]
/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/test (LoadError)
    from /home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the result of `ruby -e 'require "rack/test"'`

Comment: `/home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/test (LoadError)
 from /home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling rvm. There was a superfluous ruby executable for some reason and it messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions issue with the gem files. I can reproduce what you’re seeing if I make the `rack/test.rb` file unreadable:

```
$ ls -l `gem which rack/test`
-rw-r--r--  1 matt  staff  9723  5 Nov 19:42 /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb
$ ruby -e 'p require "rack/test"'
true
$ chmod a-r `gem which rack/test`
$ ls -l `gem which rack/test`
--w-------  1 matt  staff  9723  5 Nov 19:42 /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb
$ ruby -e 'p require "rack/test"'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/test (LoadError)
        from /Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from /Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

In other words, if the file exists but isn’t readable for some reason, then `gem which` will show the file, but trying to `require` it in Ruby means reading it, and so this will raise a `LoadError`.

Check the permissions with

```
$ ls -l `gem which rack/test`
```

They should look something like `-rw-r--r--`. If they don’t, this could be your problem. The simple fix would be to use `chmod` to correct the permissions, but you’ll want to look at the other files too, and try to determine why your permissions are wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it either. `ls -l /home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb` gives `-rw-r--r-- 1 jacky jacky 9723 2012-11-17 01:38 /home/jacky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb`.

Comment: I'm also able to `require` it if I give the full path. But adding it's parent directory to `$LOAD_PATH` doesn't help.

Comment: And one more thing: I though this might be an ownership issue since gems which I can load belong to `root:root` and gems which I can't belong to `jacky:jacky`, so I changed ownership of all files in the directory to root, but that didn't help either. It's interesting, though, because AFAIK all the gems which I can load are under root and the ones I can't are under jacky. Reinstalling rack-test with root doesn't help.